# libSVM - second best classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I am facing a classification problem, so I thought I could use libSVM and in fact everything works just fine.

Now I would like to introduce some 'tolerance' and see if my system can guess the correct label of the data (which I know a priori) in N guesses (or attempts). What I mean is this: is it possible to have libSVM output not only the label it guesses but also the second-best, third-best, ... ?

## EDIT - SOLVED

Actually I 'discovered' that I can use the option -b 1 to ask libSVM to output the probabilities. Then I can just sort them to obtain the N most likely labels.

Comment: Please note that the switch `-b 1` implements exactly the paper mentioned in my answer (using an improved algorithm, both of which are referenced [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf), in section 8).

Comment: @fg nu Thank you for the information. Of course, I accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the underlying probabilities of class classification. This is not produced by support vector machine algorithms. You can however, run an auxiliary model as described in [Platt (1999)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.1639).

Comment: Yes, probably you understood correctly. To give just an example, what I mean is an answer like "According to me this is class 1, if it's not then it is class 3, if it's not then it is class 2". So it's more likely to be 1, then 3, then 2. But if you say this is not supported, then I will look for another solution, like the one you cited.

Comment: Actually I 'discovered' that I can use the option -b 1 to ask libSVM to output the probabilities. Then I can just sort them to obtain the N most likely labels. This probably solves my problem!

Comment: @minomic Ok, I haven't really worked with libSVM in a while, so let me look up what that produces.